# How do I tell if the end user has a sound card in Java?

Tags: java, audio

I think the title says it all. My Java program uses sound and I would like to do a check at startup rather than catch an exception. If it helps I am using FreeTTS - https://freetts.sourceforge.io/.

Comment: What is the percentage of your target user population that does not have a sound "card"? What is the percentage of consumer computers without audio capability?

Comment: @LewBloch - interesting question, I suspect most people buy a computer from one of the big OEMs. (Dell, IBM, Toshiba, HP). These computers would come with Windows, a sound device and the drivers installed. Personally, I got a small local shop to set up my computer and I installed Linux on it. I sometimes have problems where my sound device is not seen in Linux. Since it happens to me, I thought there might be an easy solution so decided to ask this question. Then I can 'handle' the other rare cases in which someone does not have a working sound card but wants to run my software.

Comment: Oh, this is kind of a bad question as I can't  test it easily with my current setup. I'm sorry for taking people's time :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the java AudioSystem class for available lines:

```
/**
 * Gets a list of all audio output devices in the system
 */
public static List<Mixer> getAvailableAudioOutputDevices() {
    final ArrayList<Mixer> available = new ArrayList<>();
    final Mixer.Info[] devices = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
    final Line.Info sourceInfo = new Line.Info(SourceDataLine.class);
    for (int i=0; i<devices.length; ++i) {
        final Mixer.Info mixerInfo = devices[i];
        final Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo);
        if (mixer.isLineSupported(sourceInfo)) {
            // the device supports output, add as suitable
            available.add(mixer);
        }
    }
    return available;
}
```

Do note that this does not expliclity identify sound cards, but devices that provide audio output. Thats not necessarily the same.

Comment: This looks like it should work. I'll be testing this soon on a computer which only has 1 sound device that I can easily disable in BIOS.(I have many audio devices and Linux sometimes can't see them.) Once I've tested this, I'll accept this answer if it works. This is not a high priority item for me, so it may be a while till I get around to testing it.

Comment: Ok, so on my other computer when I disable the only sound card PalsAudio makes a dummy card. So I have no easy way to test this since I can't disable the sound card in my video card.(or else I would use Windows) Since I can't test this I can't accept the answer.